# Making a c# application on windows compatible with Mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos, visual-studio, cross-platform

I have created a c# visual studio application in Windows. The app is finished it works perfectly fine. I created this for my work where we use both windows and Mac's. Other than rewriting all of the code how can I make my application compatible for Macs. I read about Xamarin, but it looks like it's used from the beginning rather than after the application is finished. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no tool that instantly converts your program into a Mac compatible program. Platform compatability really is something that's should be decided at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing automatic that can do what you want.

I would just separe the UI from the rest of the code and write an UI for Mac with Xamarin, making use of some industrial-strength patterns like MVVM

(it's not an easy task, but can be done)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a GUI / WPF app, take a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). You will likely have to make some changes but its nothing like Xamarin which you're right, would be a complete rewrite.

If it is a webapp or console app, [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows) is fantastic and I've used it quite a bit. This is Microsoft's latest .NET implementation and it is designed to run in a container a little bit like Docker, where you have a portable "unit" of sorts.

Could benefit from a little more detail about what type of application this is, but hope that helps!